# "An exception occurred" when hitting RPlumber API from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, plumber

I am using `RPlumber` to create an API that makes some data available to the users of the API. I created an Ubuntu 16.04 server on Linode to host the API.

I have successfully installed R on the server, and all of the libraries, and am able to run the script on the machine with command `Rscript file_that_runs_rplumber.R`. When I run the script, the command line hangs with:

```
Running plumber API at http://0.0.0.0:8004
Running swagger Docs at http://127.0.0.1:8004/__docs__/
```

...so I know that the API is successfully running. I am trying to hit this endpoint from my local machine, not from the Linode server, and so I replace the `0.0.0.0` with my IP address `1.2.3.4 lets say`. When I visit `1.2.3.4:8008/__docs__/`, this page does work, and I get the auto-generated RPlumber API docs:

[image]

However when I replace `/__docs__/` with one of the API's endpoints, I receive the following:

[image]

I can see from the command line for the Linode Server that the R code associated with the endpoint **is running**, however it is simply not being returned to me. Perhaps this is a security issue, that I cannot access the endpoint on my local machine? How can I update the server so that my local machine (and any other machines as well) can access this API?

Thanks!

Comment: The api is responding, there is an error occuring within your endpoint function/handle. This is not a 404 error.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay Ive tested though, and my endpoint function works fine on my local machine. Perhaps I'm still missing a library somewhere. I will try to create a dummy endpoint that returns dummy data to confirm what you're saying.

You seem pretty certain that this isn't a firewall issue / permissions issue?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to receive the error log from this somewhere

Comment: I found the issue, but it is outside the scope of this question so I will post a new one. Thanks Bruno.

Comment: Yeah activate debug. $setDebug(TRUE) or pr_set_debug(pr, TRUE).